# Angular @Input not rendering data

Tags: javascript, angular

[image: My result looking like this]
Hello guys!
How know, what the issue there, I doing everything following guide, but input doesn't see data from parent Component, I asked chatgpt, but it gave me same result, but if I declare value of this variable in component, that trying to input,  everything is okay, and I can see a value.

```html
//child html-code
<div class="div py-6 px-4 border rounded flex items-center flex-row mb-2">
    <h1>This is child</h1>
    <p>---{{childData}}---</p>
</div>

//child component
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Iproduct } from 'src/app/data-models/Iproduct';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-component',
  templateUrl: './product-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-component.component.scss']
})
export class ProductComponentComponent {
  @Input() childData: string;
  //  @Input() childData: string = 'childData'; - this will set the value
}
//parent html code
<app-product-component>
    [childData] = "parentData"
</app-product-component>
//parent component 
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Iproduct } from './data-models/Iproduct';
import { product as data } from './data/product';

@Component({
  //setting  the selector for index.html
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Anular Application';
  products: Iproduct[] = data;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this

```
<app-product-component>
   [childData] = "parentData"
</app-product-component>
```

To

```
<app-product-component [childData]="parentData"> 
</app-product-component>
```

And if you want to pass a string directly as an input

```
<app-product-component [childData]="'someValue'"> 
</app-product-component>
```

Comment: Yeah, u a right! ‍♂️
Can I pass string like this, or should be variable declared in parent component with this name(parentData)?